# Unable to run flask in heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I'm getting app crash whenever I run my flask application in heroku

```
**This the log I get**
2021-05-07T08:16:12.395679+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `waitress-serve --listen=0.0.0.0:33507 main:create_app`
2021-05-07T08:16:16.056323+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:waitress:Serving on http://0.0.0.0:33507
2021-05-07T08:16:23.146656+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=malibu-luxury.herokuapp.com request_id=c81fd09c-29e6-48ed-bb32-73ee6f5f29bc fwd="49.205.79.67" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-07T08:17:13.001979+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-05-07T08:17:13.050236+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-05-07T08:17:13.142541+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-05-07T08:17:13.216370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-07T08:17:15.352721+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=malibu-luxury.herokuapp.com request_id=fd3e869a-7515-45c3-ace8-a322b6969c65 fwd="49.205.79.67" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**This is my flask code**

```
import MySQLdb.cursors
import re
import os
from importlib import reload
def get_port():
  return int(os.environ.get("PORT", 33507))
    return (delta.days)
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
.
.
.
        app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=get_port())
    return app
```

**This is my procfile**
`web: waitress-serve --listen=0.0.0.0:33507 main:create_app`

Comment: You should make sure you do not open flask's built-in webserver in the deployment. `app.run()` should be protected by an `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Comment: not familiar with the heroku, but from logs seems you are running server with http protocol but heroku requests with https. See 2-nd and 3-th logs. Possible that is the reason

Comment: Not sure what exactly is going wrong but it's the `PORT` stuff. You are binding to the default `33507` port instead of `$PORT` supplied by Heroku. But not sure why it is not reading the env value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Procfile you are setting the port (`33507`) which will not work, you need to use the `PORT` provided by Heroku.
You code is correct (using `int(os.environ.get("PORT", 33507))` but the Procfile should set the port differently

```
web: waitress-serve --host='0.0.0.0' --port=$PORT main:create_app
```

You have used `listen` in your Procfile, I think it can work as well when using `$PORT` instead of hardcoding 33507